# Message Broadcast simulation in Android

Tags: android

I am developing a POC Message client in Android. This app mimics a messaging application, there is no server interaction. The application starts a new chat with a random user. I want to use Broadcast receiver & message object ( as in a real application ). As there is no server interaction, I want to create a Broadcast sender part in this app, which should randomly generate some messages; My app receives these messages through Broadcast receiver, process the message & show on UI. So, while demoing, it looks like a real messaging app. 
If any one knows a simulator engine app in Android which I can use instead of developing a broadcast sender inside my app, Please let me know.
Or, if any one can suggest some better idea for implementing a mimic messaging application, please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service for your app which will always listen on ACTION/signal/message you want. It will activate your app if it gets specific message. And it will run always in the background so that user will never notice it.  Hope this will give you a hint.

Comment: What I am looking for is a broadcast sender engine. You are talking about message receiver.